# ESC POS Epson thermal printer printing image using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tcp, epson, escpos

I am facing a problem while testing to print image data to Epson printer using ESC/POS commands.
I have followed the instructions provided in the following links:

(1) https://www.visuality.pl/posts/thermal-printer-protocols-for-image-and-text

(2) http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html

(3) https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=52

Implementing image printing using Epson SDK can be a way, but I want to know how to print image data by directly sending byte arrays to my thermal printer.

In the (1) link, it says that I can print something like this by sending
`[0x1B, 0x2A, 0x0, 0x4, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x7E, 0x3C, 0x18]`

[image]

But when I try to send the same byte array using swift:

```
public extension Array where Element == Byte {

        mutating func addImage() {
            addNewLine(2)
            self += [0x1B, 0x2A, 0x0, 0x4, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x7E, 0x3C, 0x18]
            addNewLine(2)
        }
```

I get this result:

[image]

What may be the cause of this problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this source helpful? [Printer/Printer/Source/Ticket/Image.swift](https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer/blob/master/Printer/Source/Ticket/Image.swift)

Comment: @kunif please post it as an answer, your link solved my problem.

Comment: I haven't used swift or tablet/phone myself, so I can't write a detailed answer. Please answer your solution yourself.